# Search a table using React and Laravel

Tags: javascript, reactjs, laravel

I'm using Laravel to create an api for my database and React to render/fetch datas. How can I implement a search bar and a custom `<select>`/range selector along with pagination to filter my datas ?

When I was using plain HTML I used datatables.net which worked flawlessly. I want to implement something similar for react in addition of filtering.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a REST API, from there you will have a index route. https://urdomain.com/api/datas. You can acomplish that by adding a Route to the api.php in the routes folder.

Your routes/api.php would look something like this:

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;
use App\Models\Data;

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| API Routes
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Here is where you can register API routes for your application. These
| routes are loaded by the RouteServiceProvider within a group which
| is assigned the "api" middleware group. Enjoy building your API!
|
*/

Route::get('/<datas>', function (Request $request) {
  // The page parameter on the request will tell Laravel
  // What page you are aiming.
  return Data::where('some_column', '=', 'some_value')->paginate(15);
});
```

Having this setup alongside with your model, migration, etc ... you would have pagination out of the box.

Next step you need a http library such as fetch or axios to interact with the server and in react you can have an onChange on your select to fetch the data.

```
<select
  onChange={event => {
   fetch(`/api/datas?some_column=${event.target.value}`, {
     headers: { Accept: 'application/json' },
   }).then(response => response.json()).then(json => {
    // this.setState() or setVar, whatever u are doing on ur react app to render
    // the results, or useEffect if using hooks instead
   })
  }}
></select>
```

Your question is quite open but I hope u get the first steps to what you are looking for.

Cheers